# binary classification：why use +1/0 as label, what's the difference between +1/-1 or even +100/-100

Tags: machine-learning

In binary classification problem, we usually use +1 for positive label and 0 for negative label.  why is that? especially why use 0 rather than -1 for the **negative** label?

what's the difference between using -1 for negative label, or even more generally, can we use +100 for positive label and -100 for negative label?

Comment: How is this a programming problem? Its purely about ML concepts.

Answer (score 0):

As the name suggests (labeling) is used for differentiating the classes. You can use 0/1, +1/-1, cat/dog, etc. (Any name that fits your problem).
For example:

1. If you want to distinguish between cat and dog images, then use cat and dog labels.
2. If you want to detect spam, then labels will be spam/genuine.

However, because ML algorithms mostly work with numbers before training,  labels transform to numeric formats.

Comment: thanks for your replay. I mainly want to know why use 0 for negative label, not -1?

Comment: As explained by @druskacik, for some algorithms using 0/1 make more sense. (like spam problem) But it isn't always true. For example, in the case of cat/dog labeling, there are no differences between +1/0, -1/+1, or +100/-100. I think The only drawback of not using +1/0 is not following the standard.

Answer (score 0):

Using labels of 0 and 1 arises naturally from some of the historically first methods that have been used for binary classification. E.g. [logistic regression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logistic_regression) models directly the probability of an event happening, event in this case meaning belonging of an object to positive or negative class. When we use training data with labels 0 and 1, it basically means that objects with label 0 have probability of 0 belonging to a given class, and objects with label 1 have probability of 1 belonging to a given class. E.g. for spam classification, emails that are not spam would have label 0, which means they have 0 probability of being a spam, and emails that are spam would have label 1, because their probability of being a spam is 1.

So using labels of 0 and 1 makes perfect sense mathematically. When a binary classifaction model outputs e.g. 0.4 for some input, we can usually interpret this as a probability of belonging to a class 1 (although strictly it's not always the case, as pointed out for example [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/34823/can-logistic-regressions-predicted-probability-be-interpreted-as-the-confidence)).

There are classification methods that don't make use of convenient properties of labels 0 and 1, such as [support vector machines](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Support_vector_machine) or [linear discriminant analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_discriminant_analysis), but in their case no other labels would provide more convenience than 0 and 1, so using 0 and 1 is still okay.

Even encoding of classes for multiclass classification makes use of probabilities of belonging to a given class. For example in classification with three classes, objects from the first class would be encoded like `[1 0 0]`, from the second class `[0 1 0]` and the third class `[0 0 1]`, which again can be interpreted with probabilities. (This is called [one-hot encoding](https://hackernoon.com/what-is-one-hot-encoding-why-and-when-do-you-have-to-use-it-e3c6186d008f)). Output of a multiclass classification model is often a vector of form `[0.1 0.6 0.3]` which can be conveniently intepreted as a vector of class probabilities for given object.

Comment: thanks for your replay. i know use 1/0 is naturally good. but can we also use -1 for negative label? what's the drawbacks

Comment: Why would you want to do it? How do you want to model it? Labels 0 and 1 can be naturally inputted in many "loss functions" that are used in machine learning. I believe it should be possible to use -1 for the negative label, but where do you see the point of doing so?

Comment: Also, I believe this questions is more suited for a forum like CrossValidated ( https://stats.stackexchange.com/ ). StackOverflow is for problems related to programming.

Comment: @druskacik Since you know this is an off-topic question, you should not have answered it. See https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262573/why-shouldnt-i-answer-off-topic-questions-faq